# laravel date time problem on the database

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a table. There is a dateTime format in the migrations.

```
$table->dateTime('appointment_date');
```

When i create a row, the appointment date seems like that: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

My input like this:

[image]

What is the problem i could not solve. If you help me i will be glad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is about formatting.

You can use `Carbon` to make sure the correct format is going to seat in the table. For example in your controller do something like this:

```
$whatever->appointment_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->appointment_date);
```

P.S.

So, after the comment, we found that the main problem was the input format. The format should be something like this: `2021-09-05 02:46`.

Comment: Thanks, but its giving this error: Could not parse '2021 09 05 02:46': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021 09 05 02:46) at position 5 (0): Unexpected character

Comment: Can you change the input format to something like `2021-09-05 02:46`?